# How to Handle When JSON Response Returns None

Tags: python, django

I have a RESTful API call `cwObj.get_opportunities()` to return a set of records in the form of a JSON response. From the response, I reference the `ID` in each record against a second API call `cwObj.get_tickets_by_opportunity()`. This call will return a second set of records. However, often times there is not record for a particular `ID` in the JSON response returned by the second API call. The API is expecting a record for each individual call, so when there is none, I am being thrown a `IndexError: list index out of range`. Additionally, when I hardcode the ID referenced in the second API call, I am able to retrieve the data I want without errors.

*note*: `cwObj` is the basis for my API calls...

```
opportunities = cwObj.get_opportunities()

for opportunity in opportunities:
    try:
        temp = opportunity['id']
        opportunity_id = str(temp)
        presales_ticket = cwObj.get_tickets_by_opportunity(opportunity_id)
        presales_engineer = presales_ticket[0]['owner']['name']
    except KeyError:
        presales_engineer = None
```

Comment: `if presales_ticket is not None: ...`?

Comment: If *presales_ticket* is a JSON then simply check - *if presales_ticket:*

Comment: @MarkMeyer I think I need to use a `try` because when my API call reaches a record which is none, is stops iterating through the various IDs...what exception can I use to handle None?

Comment: @AnupamBera check my edit to the original code, I am receiving a `IndexError: list index out of range`. Yet, when the ID is hardcoded and not iterated through, I do not receive any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well the problem. You basically want to check if there is a particular `key` in the results you received. If it is the case you can try with that:

```py
opportunities = cwObj.get_opportunities()

for opportunity in opportunities:
    if 'id' in opportunity:
        temp = opportunity['id']
        opportunity_id = str(temp)
        presales_ticket = cwObj.get_tickets_by_opportunity(opportunity_id)
        presales_engineer = presales_ticket[0]['owner']['name']
    else:
        # What to do if there is no 'id' as key of opportunity
```

Comment: please see my edit to the original problem...I am getting an `IndexError` now

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for. but if you need to check none type
Simply Use

```
if opportunity['id'] is not None:
   temp = opportunity['id']
```

Comment: There is a SyntaxError. Please remove double `is`. Instead of `if opportunity['id'] is is not None:` it will be `if opportunity['id'] is not None:`

Comment: Actually, in Python it is good enough to say ```if opportunity['id']:``` (the is not None part will automatically be evaluated)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure cwObj.get_tickets_by_opportunity() is not returning an empty list ?

```
opportunities = cwObj.get_opportunities()

for opportunity in opportunities:
    try:
        temp = opportunity['id']
        opportunity_id = str(temp)
        presales_ticket = cwObj.get_tickets_by_opportunity(opportunity_id)
        if presales_ticket:
            if 'owner' in presales_ticket[0]:
                presales_engineer = presales_ticket[0]['owner']['name']
        else:
            # default presales ticket dict
    except KeyError:
        presales_engineer = None
```

Comment: that is my issue, often time it does return an empty list. I want to know how to handle when it does return empty so as I do not get a KeyError